# external hard drive can not copy the data capacity of more than 6GB

Tags: windows-7

I recently bought an external hard drive with 500GB capacity. hard drive is still in new condition and vacant. but when I would copy a file larger than 6GB hard drive can not copy the file. if I copy the file size of less than 6BG, the file can be copied.

what causes it?

Comment: Are you running a 32 or 64bit version of Windows 7?

Comment: What error(s) do you get when you try to copy files larger than 6gb?

Comment: What is the external drive formatted as? If its FAT32 that may be the issue.

Comment: What error you get when you choose more than 6-GB data? Also is your HDD format in NTFS or FAT32?

Answer (score 4):

Some filesystems (such as FAT32) have a 4GB [limit on file sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits)

Some cheap hard drives are [fake](http://www.cracktwo.com/2011/04/chinese-fake-hard-drive.html)

[image: fake HDD 1]
[image: fake HDD 2]

Comment: And that's how SSD was invented.