# Is it possible for HDDs to have a fake/spoofed capacity similar to what is done with fake high size flash drives?

Tags: hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, spoofing

You often see or hear about these insane flash drives with 2TB capacity that sell for ridiculously low prices that actually are 16GB or 32GB flash drives but keep overwriting data so it looks like they hold a higher capacity.
But I was wondering, can this happen to hard disc drives too or can scammers only use this technique on flash-based storage?

Comment: I think in general yes, you could get an HDD to misstate its overall capacity, though i don't think overwriting in a loop would be nearly as easy with an HDD as it would be with flash storage. Just my hunch.

Comment: Seems like an obvious XY problem. You should be rather looking into as to how to avoid these scams in general. As capacity is only one of many of problems you may encounter. You can get much worse transfer speeds, refurbished old/broken disks that are likely to break quickly, etc. Chinese are getting more and more creative. Buying from trusted sources rather than e.g. ShenguonghongXSFH kind of shops on Amazon is one of solutions.

Comment: I'm not intending to buy a drive that looks suspicious, I don't want to support that kind of market. I was just curious about the possibility and if they could be made is all. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Flash-based storage that is most likely to be faked are ready-to-use, consumer-friendly storage devices such as USB sticks and SD cards. The consumer does not need to format or prepare the device prior to use; simply insert the storage device into the PC or whatever equipment. But HDDs typically need to have cables attached, brackets and/or screws installed, and the drive formatted. Very likely an HDD with a fake capacity would be detected soon after purchase, and a product return instigated. Whereas the fake USB flash drive or SD card might not be detected for days/weeks/months if ever.

Answer (score 1):

*In theory* they could. HDDs have a controller and that controller has a firmware. That firmware could be rewritten to report a larger capacity than the drive actually has.

The question is though, why would anyone want to?

HDDs aren't particularly expensive to begin with, and while you can put a [16GB memory stick into an enclosure with a couple of bolts](https://superuser.com/a/440202/19943) to make it feel like an HDD, the only real thing you would have a cost benefit from using HDDs to act as a useful fake for would be an SSD and that would be immediately suspicious because it weighs significantly more.

And even then why would you bother using the HDD when you've already invested time and money in the cheaper memory sticks and have thousands of them lying around. You already have your fake sized drive, why do you need to reinvent a version that costs you more? You just repackage the same thing in a different enclosure and carry on.

Faking a HDD size doesn't really net you big profits compared to using memory sticks.

If they're going to send you a fake 22tb drive then it's cheaper and just as easy to give you yet another 16GB memory stick and handful of bolts.

There may well be a market for HDDs with faked sizes, but they're not likely to be headed for consumer markets as there's no real big profit there and most people selling HDDs in any quantity will have a known good supply chain and fakes will quickly be noticed and expunged. Most reputable PC component sellers are going to have vetted and controlled supply chains and are unlikely to buy grey market parts. A sudden dearth of cheaper parts in the grey market while the normal market price and stock levels remain the same is going to be a pretty big red flag.

The reason fake drives work so well on amazon and ebay is because sellers can appear, sell a bunch of crap and then vanish and they are unlikely to bother using higher value inputs. Memory stick cheap, HDD less cheap. Higher value items like HDDs are unlikely to be faked in the same way and are unlikely to get into the supply chain the same way.

Comment: Your answer focuses on cost and profit per unit, and thus overlooks the real difference. There's a much larger and much-less tech-savvy (consumer) market for flash drives & SD cards than HDDs. Scammers target the easy mark, and go where there are many marks/opportunities.